# why am I getting "This field is required." on loading of the page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a form in my template which I have used the django-crispy-forms to implement. I have the models.py, and then created the forms.py and then used it in my views.py. I don't know why I keep having the "This field is required." whenever I load the page. I have some feelings that it has to do with the views.py thou. I would be glad if i could receive some solutions. Thanks

This is the image of the page.
[image]

models.py

```
class add_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Manager_Name = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    choices = (
            ("online", "online"),
            ("in person", "in person")
        )

    description = models.TextField(default='')
    syllabus = models.TextField(default='')
    classroom = models.CharField(choices=choices, default='in person', max_length=12)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=14, default='')
    student = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(add_teacher_by_manager)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(course_schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name
```

views.py

```
def manager_page(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        manager_id = request.POST.get('manager_id')
        manager_name = request.POST.get('manager_name')

        form3 = AddCourses()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form3 = AddCourses(request.POST)
            if form3.is_valid():
                form3.save()
                return redirect("/")

        # get_course_details = add_course.objects.all()

        courses = add_courses.objects.all().order_by('-id')

        get_supervisor_man=manager_supervisor.objects.filter(manager_id=manager_id)

        Manager_login_information_get1 = Manager_login_information.objects.get(manager_ID=manager_id)
        # print(Manager_login_information_get1)

        manager_usid = Manager_login_information_get1.manager_ID
        manager_usname = Manager_login_information_get1.manager_Name

        context9 = {'manager_id':manager_id, 'manager_name':manager_name, 'form1':form1, 'form2':form2, 'form3':form3, 'courses':courses, 'Manager_login_information_get1':Manager_login_information_get1}
        return render(request, 'manager_page.html', context9)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Can you also post your model here? a solution might be to add "blank=True" to your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#blank

Comment: Check the question again, i have added it.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you have to add [blank=True](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#blank) to allow blank fields.(default is False)

So you model will look something like this:

```
class add_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked for all fields except the student and teacher field which are having manytomanyfield relations.

Comment: No problem! did you run the migration again ? i thought that would work too on the m2m fields.

Comment: also how can I prefill the manager field with the current manager information, the manager field is a foreign key.

Comment: To get the current manager/user info you have to make a queryset inside your view. apply that to the 'context9' to acces it from the template where you can loop over it.

Comment: That results in that a user can fill out the field as blank, not validating the input as required.